# D3: Can't select a subset of my dataset

Tags: d3.js

I would like to select a subset of data with `.select()` or `.selectAll()`.

For example, I have a dataset:

```
var dataset = [4,5,6,7,9,56]
```

Each number of this dataset is bound to an SVG `<rect>`:

```
svg.selectAll("rect")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append("rect");
```

Now I would like to select only a subset of data for applying some stuff on it (colouring in yellow in my case).

This works for colouring *every* the `<rect>`:

```
var allRect = myselection.selectAll("rect")
  .attr("fill","rgb(255, 255, 0)");
```

But I would like to select, for example, only the `<rect>`s corresponding to a number between 5 and 7. Or at least the `<rect>` corresponding to a specific number from my dataset.

I tried:

```
var specificRect = myselection.selectAll("rect")[5:9]

var specificRect = myselection.selectAll("rect")[5]

var specificRect = myselection.selectAll("rect")[2,3,4]

var specificRect = myselection.selectAll("rect").data(dataset)[1]
```

None of those are working. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can post an answer to your own question and accept that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was the use of ".filter".

```
var specificRect = myselection.selectAll("rect").data(dataset)
.filter(function(d) { return (d >= 5 && d <= 9) })
```